# C# possible to have a constructor in an abstract class?

Tags: c#

I have 1 abstract class that is calling a static method which up until now didn't require any parameters. This has recently changed. In reality the static method exists in another class and sets the value of BaseMessageDirectory, but in this example below I have simplified things...

So now I want to create my derived classes in such a way that they can initialize some required properties in the parent class during the inheritance, is this possible?

For example....

```
 public abstract class ParentClass
    {
          protected string BaseMessageDirectory;

          protected ParentClass(EnumOperationType operationType)
             {
                if(operationtype == 1)
                  {
                     BaseMessageDirectory = "one";
                  }
                else
                  {
                     BaseMessageDirectory = "two";
                  }
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can define a constructor, and all child classes will have to call it:

```
public class Child : ParentClass
{
    public Child() : base(EnumOperationType.One) { ... }
}
```

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly - the constructors in the abstract class become mandatory for the child classes?

Comment: Yes.. The child classes must call one of the base class constructors.

Comment: Yes, classes have to call one of their parent's constructors from their constructors - if the abstract class has a default constructor then you don't need to specify it explictly (although you can).

Comment: I would say at least one of them. If you also have a parameterless constructor in the base class, than it will be the default to be called.

Comment: Although you can do this like lee said but I don't think it's a good idea because your abstract class is doing something that affect its child behavior . the question is why parent class should select the base directory for its child class? what happen if a new child class with a new operation type is added to your code? you should change the parent too.I think every child class can have its own base directory set in its constructor or there can be a BaseDirectoryProvider (strategy pattern) that can provide this information for each class in parent class